# Offsetting Pointer to String in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to print 80 characters of my string, increment 80 characters, and then print another 80 characters.

Currently this line:
`offset = myString + 80;` is just pointing to the beginning of the myString array rather than pointing to myString[80]. I expect it to print different results but my output is the same both times.

Resulting output: At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praese

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char myString[1024] = "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praeseAt vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.";
    char buf[80];
    char* offset;

    sscanf(myString, "%80c", buf);
    fwrite(myString , 1 , 80 , stdout);

    printf("\n");

    offset = myString + 80;
    sscanf(offset, "%80c", buf);
    fwrite(offset , 1 , 80 , stdout);
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that line is copying the array? How are you checking? What specifically did you test, what was the result, and what result did you expect instead?

Comment: Well not copying, but my offset pointer is pointing to the memory location of myString. I checked this by printing offset individually after setting it to myString + 80.  My expected result was to set the offset to point to myString[80], and then read the next 80 characters of myString. What actually happens is it just prints the same exact 80 characters as before.

Comment: `inc(a);` is `a = a + 1;`

Comment: Isn't `myString` hardcoded to be the same for index 0-79 and index 80-159? It looks the same.

Comment: If you have a string "abcdabcd" and you print index 0-3 and index 4-7 they will look the same. That's what you're doing here.

Comment: @EdmCoff Wow. Yeah When I first was testing with 80 chars I meant to copy the full lorem ipsum in to test. This was clearly just a mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first 80 characters in `myString` are the same as the next 80 characters, so it makes sense that you'd see the same thing both times.

Also, the call to `sscanf` is writing the 80 bytes at `offset` to `buf`.  There's no real need for this, so you can remove it.

Comment: The string was going off my screen so I didn't realize I made a mistake with my string. Sorry, and thanks for the clarification.